# Optimizing Cypher Query Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to write a query in Cypher and run it on Neo4j.

The query is:

Given some start vertexes, walk edges and find all vertexes that is connected to any of start vertex.

```
(start)-[*]->(v)
```

for every edge E walked

```
if startVertex(E).someproperty != endVertex(E).someproperty, output E.
```

The graph may contain cycles.

[image: example query]

For example, in the graph above, vertexes are grouped by "group" property. The query should return 7 rows representing the 7 orange colored edges in the graph.

If I write the algorithm by myself it would be a simple depth / breadth first search, and for every edge visited if the filter condition is true, output this edge. The complexity is O(V+E)

But  I can't express this algorithm in Cypher since it's very different language.

Then i wrote this query:

find all reachable vertexes

```
(start)-[*]->(v), reachable = start + v.
```

find all edges starting from any of reachable. if an edge ends with any reachable vertex and passes the filter, output it.

```
match (reachable)-[]->(n) where n in reachable and reachable.someprop != n.someprop
```

so the Cypher code looks like this:

```
MATCH (n:Col {schema:"${DWMDATA}",table:"CHK_P_T80_ASSET_ACCT_AMT_DD"})
WITH n MATCH (n:Col)-[*]->(m:Col)
WITH collect(distinct n) + collect(distinct m) AS c1
UNWIND c1 AS rn
MATCH (rn:Col)-[]->(xn:Col) WHERE rn.schema<>xn.schema and xn in c1
RETURN rn,xn
```

The performance of this query is not good as I thought. There are index on :Col(schema)

I am running neo4j 2.3.0 docker image from dockerhub on my windows laptop. Actually it runs on a linux virtual machine on my laptop.

My sample data is a small dataset that contains 0.1M vertexes and 0.5M edges. For some starting nodes it takes 60 or more seconds to complete this query. Any advice for optimizing or rewriting the  query? Thanks.

The following code block is the logic I want:

```
 VertexQueue1 = (starting vertexes);
 VisitedVertexSet = (empty);
 EdgeSet1 = (empty);
 While (VertexSet1 is not empty)
 {
     Vertex0 = VertexQueue1.pop();
     VisitedVertexSet.add(Vertex0);
     foreach (Edge0 starting from Vertex0)
     {
           Vertex1 = endingVertex(Edge0);
           if (Vertex1.schema <> Vertex0.schema)
           {
               EdgeSet1.put(Edge0);
           }
           if (VisitedVertexSet.notContains(Vertex1) 
               and VertexQueue1.notContains(Vertex1)) 
           {
               VertexQueue1.push(Vertex1);
           }
     }
 }
 return EdgeSet1;
```

EDIT:

The profile result shows that expanding all paths has a high cost. Looking at the row number, it seems that Cypher exec engine returns all paths but I want distint edge list only.

LEFT one:

```
match (start:Col {table:"F_XXY_DSMK_ITRPNL_IDX_STAT_W"})
,(start)-[*0..]->(prev:Col)-->(node:Col)
 where prev.schema<>node.schema 
return distinct prev,node
```

RIGHT one:

```
MATCH (n:Col {schema:"${DWMDATA}",table:"CHK_P_T80_ASSET_ACCT_AMT_DD"})
WITH n MATCH (n:Col)-[*]->(m:Col)
WITH collect(distinct n) + collect(distinct m) AS c1
UNWIND c1 AS rn
MATCH (rn:Col)-[]->(xn:Col) WHERE rn.schema<>xn.schema and xn in c1
RETURN rn,xn
```

[image: profile result]

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is that it's easy to get an explosion in the number of paths that you can explore with an open-ended variable path (it's relationships that aren't traversed twice in a path, BTW, not nodes).  I don't think there is a way in Cypher to stop browsing a path because the properties of two adjacent nodes are different without loading the whole path first and then rejecting it, unfortunately.  You might consider either using the Java APIs directly or making an unmanaged extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Cypher lets this be much easier than you're expecting it to be, if I'm understanding the query.  Try this:

```
MATCH (start:Col {schema:"${DWMDATA}",table:"CHK_P_T80_ASSET_ACCT_AMT_DD"})-->(node:Col)
WHERE start.schema <> node.schema
RETURN start, node
```

Though I'm not sure why you're comparing the `schema` property on the nodes.  Isn't the `schema` for the start node fixed by the value that you pass in?

I might not be understanding the query though.  If you're looking for more than just the nodes connected to the start node, you could do:

```
MATCH
  (start:Col {schema:"${DWMDATA}",table:"CHK_P_T80_ASSET_ACCT_AMT_DD"})
  (start)-[*0..]->(prev:Col)-->(node:Col)
WHERE prev.schema <> node.schema
RETURN prev, node
```

That open-ended variable length relationship specification might be slow, though.

Also note that when Cypher is browsing a particular path it stops which it finds that it's looped back onto some node (**EDIT** *relationship*, not *node*) in the path  matched so far, so cycles aren't really a problem.

Also, is the `DWMDATA` value that you're passing in interpolated?  If so, you should think about using parameters for security / performance:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment I have a couple of thoughts.  First limiting to `DISTINCT path` isn't going to help because every path that it finds is distinct.  What you want is the distinct set of pairs, I think, which I think could be achieved by just adding `DISTINCT` to the query:

```
MATCH
  (start:Col {schema:"${DWMDATA}",table:"CHK_P_T80_ASSET_ACCT_AMT_DD"})
  (start)-[*0..]->(prev:Col)-->(node:Col)
WHERE prev.schema <> node.schema
RETURN DISTINT prev, node
```

Here is another way to go about it which may or may not be more efficient, but might at least give you an idea for how to go about things differently:

```
MATCH
  path=(start:Col {schema:"${DWMDATA}",table:"CHK_P_T80_ASSET_ACCT_AMT_DD"})-->(node:Col)
WITH rels(path) AS rels
UNWIND rels AS rel
WITH DISTINCT rel
WITH startNode(rel) AS start_node, endNode(rel) AS end_node
WHERE start_node.schema <> end_node.schema
RETURN start_node, end_node
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) I need the open-ended variable length relationship. I ran the second block of code in your answer and it returned all possible paths of  start, prev and node. On my sample data (v=0.1M), after 300s waiting the query returned 9M rows. I think for my data, the desired output should be about 300rows ( representing  300 different edges ).  I added `(prev)->[path]->(node) return distinct path` but it doesn't affect the execution plan outputed by EXPLAIN.  Is there a way to tell neo4j that " you just need to visit every edge and node once" and speed up the query?

Comment: By adding DISTINCT the query returned distinct set of pairs but the perfomance does not improve. It seems the execution engine calcuated all possible paths and I don't need every different paths, just the distinct edge set is Ok. I added a code block at the last of the question to explain the algorithm I want to execute (though It's not parallel but I can improve it) . So can I tune the Cypher execution engine to do the query like the algorithm I described?

Comment: The code example was helpful.  Made another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that this would be faster, but here's another way to try:

```
MATCH (start:Col)-[*]->(node:Col)
WHERE start.property IN {property_values}

WITH collect(ID(node)) AS node_ids

MATCH (:Col)-[r]->(node:Col)
WHERE ID(node) IN node_ids
WITH DISTINCT r
RETURN startNode(r) AS start_node, endNode(r) AS end_node
```

I suspect that the problem in all cases is with the open-ended variable length path.  I've actually asked on the Slack group to try to get a better understanding of how it works.  In the meantime, for all the queries that you try I would suggest prefixing them with the `PROFILE` keyword to get a report from Neo4j on what parts of the query are slow.

Comment: The `PROFILE` report of this query is similar to the right one in the last section of question. It seems the engine visited every edge more than once in VarLenExpand so the number of returning rows is large. Wondering if there are any way to tell the engine to do as my algorithm described.

Comment: Why would you collect the id's and then match again? If this query is ok, then I added a variant in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// this is very inefficient!
MATCH (start:Col)-[*]->(node:Col)
WHERE start.property IN {property_values}
WITH distinct node
MATCH (prev)-[r]->(node)
RETURN distinct prev, node;
```

you might be better off with this:

```
MATCH (start:Col)
WHERE start.property IN {property_values}

MATCH (node:Col)
WHERE shortestPath((start)-[*]->(node)) IS NOT NULL

MATCH (prev)-[r]->(node)
RETURN distinct prev, node;
```

Comment: the first query completed in  5 minutes, but the second query didn't complete in 30 minutes …… will neo4j try to execute the shortest path algorithm for EVERY nodes once in `shortestPath((start)-[*]->(node))`? if that's true I think this query would be slow.